# How to call method on a JSX element when writing functional react

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have recently started using React and Redux. One thing that often messes with my brain is how to re-write all the code examples from documentations that are usually written object based to my functional code base.

I am now in one of those situations; I can not find a way to call a method belonging to `react-custom-scrollbars` ([link to docs](https://github.com/malte-wessel/react-custom-scrollbars/tree/master/docs)) which I am using in one of my components. Below is a simplified version of the component. I have commented out the section where I would like to call the method `scrollToBottom()`.

Bonus question: If I skip using the `onUpdate()` event, how would I go proceed if I want to call `scrollToBottom()` when a message is appended to the `messages` array?

```
const Chat = ({messages, app, keyDown, pressSend, setMessage, toggleEnter}) => {

  return (
    <div id="orbit-chat-content">
      <Scrollbars
        onUpdate={() => {
          //
          // HERE I WANT TO SCROLL TO BOTTOM
          //
          // this.scrollToBottom()
          //
        }}
        className="react-scrollbar">
        <div id="orbit-chat-conversation">
          { messages.map(message => <Message {...message} />) }
        </div>
      </Scrollbars>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

Thank you very much for taking your time to look at this!

Comment: Stateless components don't have an instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question:

Stateless components don't have **refs**. Which you would normally use to access the scrollbars instance.

Your real problem:

> ...how to re-write **all** the
>   code examples from documentations that are usually written object
>   based to my functional code base.

You don't have to. Statefull components are not deprecated or so. They are the base. PureRender Components / Functional components, are just an addition to the stack to provide a way of writing small independent components, like a **Button**.

Of course you can write a whole app only with stateless components, but if you need internal state, access to instances, some internal logic, you can and should use Normal Components too.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks for taking your time!